# Express js promise.all returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express, promise

Hi i am newbie to express and promise, i am trying to call multiple asynchronous function using promise.all from express router, but it returns undefined, please guide me to solve the issue .

**user.js //routes**

```
var findAllUsersDetails = function(router){
        router.post('/api/v1/users/getAllUserFormDetails', 
        function (req, res) {
            Promise.all([
                userModel.getAllUsers(req), 
                userModel.getAllUsers(req), 
            ])
            .then((data) => console.log(data))
            .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    });
}
```

**user.js // models**

```
var userModel = {
getAllUsers : function(req){
    var string = "";
    var id_company = req['user'].id_company;
    var dbConnection = dbConnectionCreator();
    var getAllUsers = getAllUsersSqlString(string, id_company);
    console.log("ANGEL: finding all employees");

    dbConnection.query(getAllUsers, function(error, results, fields){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              console.log(results);
            if (error) {
                dbConnection.destroy();
                console.log("error: ", error);
                return reject (err);
            } else if (results.length === 0) {
                resolve("User not found.");
            } else {
                resolve(results);
                //return (callback({employeeData: results}));
            }
          })
    });     
},
}
module.exports = userModel;
```

Comment: Beginner mistake, returning something from callback returns it to caller of the callback not where callback is created. Read `getAllUsers` carefully. It, in fact, returns nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`userModel.getAllUsers(req)` should return `Promise` a.e.:

```
function getAllUsers(req) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
     //...
   });
 }
```

In your case `dbConnection.query(getAllUsers, function(error, results, fields)` returns `Promise` therefore you can write something like:

```
getAllUsers : function(req){

    var string = "";
    var id_company = req['user'].id_company;
    var dbConnection = dbConnectionCreator();
    var getAllUsers = getAllUsersSqlString(string, id_company);
    console.log("ANGEL: finding all employees");

    return dbConnection.query(getAllUsers, function(error, results, fields){
//   ^^^
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              console.log(results);
            if (error) {
                dbConnection.destroy();
                console.log("error: ", error);
                return reject (err);
            } else if (results.length === 0) {
                resolve("User not found.");
            } else {
                resolve(results);                    
            }
          })
    });     
},
```

Comment: Yes, you guys are right, return Promise is the issue and dbConnection.query is not returning promise's resolve or reject

Answer (score 1):

Your `getAllUsers` function is expected to return `Promise`, but is returning undefined(nothing).

The promise is returned to `dbConnection.query` but not to the `getAllUsers` function.

You can try adding `return`.

`return dbConnection.query`

if this doesn't work, then dbquery doesn't return the callback which was returned to it.

You might need to find an alternative to solve this.

Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

What i did is i placed the dbconnection within promise function and now i can return promise with the results of dbConnection.query()

```
getAllUsers : function(req){
    var string = "";
    var id_company = req['user'].id_company;
    var dbConnection = dbConnectionCreator();
    var getAllUsers = getAllUsersSqlString(string, id_company);
    console.log("ANGEL: finding all employees");

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
        dbConnection.query(getAllUsers, function(error, results, fields){ //
          console.log(results);
            if (error) {
                dbConnection.destroy();
                console.log("error: ", error);
                return reject (err);
            } else if (results.length === 0) {
                resolve("User not found.");
            } else {
                resolve(results);
                //return (callback({employeeData: results}));
            }
        });
      });
```

Thanks for your immediate reply, actually i understood issue is because of returning promise from your answers.

Comment: You welcome to accept any answer helped you to sort things out.